PostgreSQL assign a query result to variable
I want to list all my tables and for each table call a procedure ID_resync on the id column
This statement fails at retrieving the l_current_max which is NULL in the LOG
so the problematic line appears to be execute l_statement into l_current_max;
create or replace procedure ID_resync(table_name_in text, id_column_in text )
 language plpgsql
as $$
declare 
    k_select_max_id constant text = 'select max(%I) from %I'; 
       
    k_alter_key_seq constant text = 'alter table %I alter column %I restart with %s'; 
       
    l_current_max integer;   
    l_statement   text; 
   
begin 
    l_statement = format(k_select_max_id, id_column_in, table_name_in); 
    raise notice '%',E'GET CURRENT MAX:\n ' || l_statement; 
    execute l_statement into l_current_max; 
   
    l_current_max = l_current_max + 1;  -- set for new sequence
    l_statement = format(k_alter_key_seq, table_name_in, id_column_in, l_current_max);
    raise notice '%',E'SET NEW SEQUENCE:\n ' || l_statement; 
    execute l_statement;
   
    commit; 
     
end;
$$;


DO
$$
    DECLARE
        rec record;
    BEGIN
        FOR rec IN 
            SELECT table_name, column_name
              FROM information_schema.columns
             WHERE table_schema='public'
                AND column_name='id'
        LOOP
            raise notice 'name: %', rec.table_name;
            CALL ID_resync( rec.table_name ,'id');
 
        END LOOP;
    END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

error
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at end of input
  Where: PL/pgSQL function id_resync(text,text) line 20 at EXECUTE
SQL statement "CALL ID_resync( rec.table_name ,'id')"
PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 10 at CALL

LOG:
name: ad
GET CURRENT MAX:
 select max(id) from ad
VALUE OF l_current_max: <NULL>
SET NEW SEQUENCE:
 alter table ad alter column id restart with 

After comments I also tried this:
    if l_current_max is not null 
        then
        raise notice 'VALUE OF l_current_max: %', l_current_max; 
        l_current_max = l_current_max + 1;
        l_statement = format(k_alter_key_seq, table_name_in, id_column_in, l_current_max);
        raise notice '%',E'SET NEW SEQUENCE:\n ' || l_statement; 
        execute l_statement;
        commit; 

    END IF;


Use COALESCE(l_current_max, 0) + 1?

It appears as though the ad table is empty which would result in max(id) returning null. A condition I did not anticipate in my initial reply to your original question. (My bad!). You can account for it the by placing an if l_current_max is not null then l_current_max =l_current_max.... That will bypass resetting the sequence altogether or use COALESCE() as Adrian Klaver suggests.

@Belayer thanks for the suggestion, I tried it but it does not seem to work. I added the code in the question. I also triedCOALESCE(l_current_max, 0) + 1 instead of l_current_max = l_current_max + 1
